# X-Sendfile or X-Accel-Redirect equivalent for IIS/.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, asmx

I have an ASMX web-service which creates a file given a few paramaters, instead of serving it as Base64 encoded XML I would like IIS to serve the file to free my worker for the next job. The serialization is pretty expensive and totally unnecessary.

Comment: Please explain in more detail - how does IIS serve the file now? What is the relationship between the ASMX web service creating the file and IIS serving it?

Comment: IIS simply reads the file off the disk, the web service now replies with a URL and the client GETs it. It would save the client a round trip if it could simply serve the file it created and then delete it.

Comment: It would also be hugely useful for protected files, where you don't want to make them available in the web root. You can set up other webservers (ningx and lighthttpd, possibly others) to do this. The applicability extends way beyond just this request. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286270/how-to-password-protect-streaming-videos-with-php for an example with PHP and lighthttpd.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for a similar solution. It appears this fits the bill:

http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

Specifically look at the x-sendfile piece.

Answer (score 1):

> X-Sendfile and X-Accel-Redirect Support for IIS 7.x
>
> This module provides basic support for X-Sendfile and X-Accel-Redirect
>   headers.

https://github.com/stakach/IIS-X-Sendfile-plugin

http://advancedcontrol.com.au/blog/2011/10/4/web-applications-on-iis-7x.html